# Will SDK Manager suppport for windows-8

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-8, sdk, windows-8.1

Will SDK Manager support for windows-8. I installed the android sdk for Windows 8.
But when I open the android sdk manager, a cmd-like screen just briefly flashes on for half a second then disappears. I have no idea what's going on and how to get this thing working.

Answer (score 4):

I am facing same problem on Windows 8.1.
I saw following solution on internet:

---

Open /sdk/tools/android.bat file.
and 
change 
“set java_exe=” line to
set java_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"

Note:

### The java.exe path could be different on your system.

But it didn't work in my case, try it on your side.
One thing strange is that if we run "/sdk/tools/android.bat" directly it works, but it does not run through "SDK Manager.exe" file.

Any other person facing same problem and got any solution?

Comment: i have the same problem, did u find any solution for this issue??

Answer (score 1):

> Will SDK Manager support for windows-8

Yes, it works perfectly in Windows 8 also.

### Follow below steps which worked for me :-

1. Go to (sdk-folder)/tools folder (For me it is C:\Users\Ajay\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools)
2. Open the file android.bat in any text editor.
3. Go to the line where `set java_exe` is located
4. Set the Path of `java.exe` which is located in your JRE. For ex : *`set java_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"`*
5. Save the file and try it again, now it should work !

Answer (score 1):

Match your Machin's Java bit system with your android SDK bit system, i.e install a JDK x86 if you got android SDK x86. And usually android SDK works fine with Java x86 versions.